# hex size in pyplot.hexbin based on frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

Is there a way to increase the reltive sizes of hexagons in pyplot.hexbin based on their frequency? 
I can only see binsize for the keyword arguments, which affects the number of hexes, but not their size.

But in [this article](http://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/hexagonal-binning/) (around 2/3 in under the heading 'Multivariate Hexagonal Binning'), it discusses drawing hexagons with size proportional to count in order to more clearly observe trends (see following image taken from that article)

[image]

Have I missed a keyword argument that allows this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you did not miss any keyword argument. Matplotlib hexbin plots use a constant bin size throughout the plot. For the plot shown I also do not quite understand how that plot is consitently produced, other than using a normal scatterplot.

Comment: Possibly you can look at the [source for `hexbin`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L4336), figure out how it works and adapt it for your use.  You would need to include the modified function in your project.

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the purpose of using hexbins in the first place? Why not use disks instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the plot in question there is no advantage of using hexagonal binning since the hexagons have different sizes and hence would not allow a consistent binning throughout the plot. You may however use a constant binning and just shrink the cells, which do not have the maximal value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

a = np.random.rand(200,2)
b = np.random.rand(200)
c = np.concatenate((a,np.c_[b,b]), axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

hexbin = ax.hexbin(c[:,0],c[:,1],gridsize=20, linewidth=0 )

def sized_hexbin(ax,hc):
    offsets = hc.get_offsets()
    orgpath = hc.get_paths()[0]
    verts = orgpath.vertices
    values = hc.get_array()
    ma = values.max()
    patches = []
    for offset,val in zip(offsets,values):
        v1 = verts*val/ma+offset
        path = Path(v1, orgpath.codes)
        patch = PathPatch(path)
        patches.append(patch)

    pc = PatchCollection(patches)
    pc.set_array(values)
    ax.add_collection(pc)
    hc.remove()

sized_hexbin(ax,hexbin)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

For comparisson, one may transmit the same information via a scatter plot. This code is potentially much more intuitive than the above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

a = np.random.rand(200,2)
b = np.random.rand(200)
c = np.concatenate((a,np.c_[b,b]), axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

h, ex, ey = np.histogram2d(c[:,0],c[:,1], bins=np.linspace(0,1,20))

X,Y = np.meshgrid(ex[:-1]+np.diff(ex)/2.,ey[:-1]+np.diff(ey)/2.)

ax.scatter(X.flatten(),Y.flatten(), 
           c=h.T.flatten(), s=h.T.flatten()**2,
           marker="h")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried implementing your first solution in my code and I'm having trouble changing the size based on the density. Instead, the size of my hexagons are based on a column that I used to color the data. Here is the question in full:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072873/hex-size-in-matplotlib-hexbins-based-on-density-of-nearby-points

Comment: Which of the two solutions did you try? Of course you will need to set the size you want in either case (here, the color and size are the same, but of course they can be different if you want). Please use minimal examples for questions.

Comment: I tried your first solution with the hexbins() method. I have minimal examples in this stack overflow question that I asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072873/hex-size-in-matplotlib-hexbins-based-on-density-of-nearby-points

Comment: No, that's not a [mcve]. It's not runnable by itself, and I cannot know which quantities you want to use for which visualization part.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the example with minimally reproducible code. Any help would be much appreciated!