# Change hex size based on frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code that creates the following plot with hexbins. For context, df['PCT_DIFF'] is on the range [0,1]. It is the column that I will color each area of the graph by.

```
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))    
ax.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'],C=df['PCT_DIFF'],bins=20, gridsize=50, \
            cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r', 10), edgecolors='black')
```

[image: hexbins]

This is the original chart with each point plotted

```
plt.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], s=10, marker='o', c='#007A33')
```

[image: orig plot]

I'd like to change the size of the hexes in the first picture based on the density of the dots shown in the second picture.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844600/hex-size-in-pyplot-hexbin-based-on-frequency), but this is what was shown. I passed the cm.get_cmap() and edgecolors to the PatchCollection() in the sized_hexbin method

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
hexbin = ax.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'],C=df['PCT_DIFF'], bins=20, gridsize=50, extent=[-275, 275, -50, 425])
sized_hexbin(ax,hexbin)
```

[image: proposed solution]

Comparing this graph with the second one, it looks like the density isn't correct. The hexes under the basket should be larger and there are no hexes to the left of the basket where there are dots. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844600/hex-size-in-pyplot-hexbin-based-on-frequency?

Comment: @Pygirl I tried that but the size was flipped

Comment: @JohanC when I ran it with my data the small hexagons were the areas with a higher density and the hexagons that were larger had a higher density

Comment: Flip your data with [::-1]? Which one of the examples did you try? Post the code?

Comment: @JohanC Sorry for being vague, I updated the post with more context and an attempted solution

Comment: @JohanC I removed the test data because I couldn't figure out how to explain what I was trying to do. I'm changing the code of the linked solution, but I don't understand how it changed the colors and removed the outline and how it is working. In the last snippet of code in my solution I showed how I integrated the code

Comment: @JohanC I updated the link in the post. `df['PCT_DIFF` is a column with a min of -1 and a max of 1. I changed the color array to `c=1-df['PCT_DIFF']` and got a result that looked close to what I wanted. How can I change the colors back to `cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r', 10)` and the edgecolors as black? Is there a way to specify the max and min sizes of the scaled hexagons? Here is a link to the test data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12SaBJA097SsD1ji6BpJPtTXOM45BXfYP

Comment: Well, Ernest's solution supposes positive values. You can just adapt Ernest's code to change the size with some factors. You can set the colormap as a parameter to `PatchCollection(patches, cmap=..., edgecolors=...)`.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for all of your help. I was able to change to color and edgecolor, but it looks like each hex has a different color now, and I'd like to be able to group the colors like in the first figure. How can I do this? Also, could you point me to the part in his method that I need to modify? I haven't been able to figure out what his code is doing, as this is the first time I've used hexbin in matplotlib

Comment: Maybe `cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu', 10)` instead of `'RdYlBu_r'` to get a reverse version of the same colormap?

Comment: @JohanC That helped me reverse the color scale but I'm still looking how to color them based on one column in my df. Dp you know which parameter in the code can I do this with?

Comment: The values for the colors are in `pc.set_array(values)`. Just setting other values changes the colors assigned to each hexagon. You also need to set either the norm or the `pc.set_clim(vmin=min(...), vmax=max(...))` to tell which value gets mapped to the lowest and which to the highest color.

Comment: @JohanC can you post this as an answer so I can give you credit?