# Hex size in matplotlib hexbins based on density of nearby points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got the following code which produces the following figure

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(3)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['X'] = list(np.random.randint(100, size=100)) + list(np.random.randint(30, size=100))
df['Y'] = list(np.random.randint(100, size=100)) + list(np.random.randint(30, size=100))

df['Bin'] = df.apply(lambda row: .1 if row['X'] < 30 and row['Y'] < 30 else .9, axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'])
```

[image: scatter]

I graphed the data using hexbins, as noted below

```
from matplotlib import cm

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
hexbin = ax.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'], C=df['Bin'], gridsize=20, cmap= cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r'),edgecolors='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: hexbins]

I'd like to change the size of the hexagons based on the density of the points plotted in the area that a hexagon covers. For example, the hexagons in the bottom left (where the points are compact) will be larger than the hexagons everywhere else (where the points are sparse). Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844600/hex-size-in-pyplot-hexbin-based-on-frequency), but I can't figure out how to color the hexes based on df['Bin'], or how to set the min and max hex size.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
hexbin = ax.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'], C=df['Bins'], gridsize=20, cmap= cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r'),edgecolors='black')
def sized_hexbin(ax,hc):
    offsets = hc.get_offsets()
    orgpath = hc.get_paths()[0]
    verts = orgpath.vertices
    values = hc.get_array()
    ma = values.max()
    patches = []
    for offset,val in zip(offsets,values):
        v1 = verts*val/ma+offset
        path = Path(v1, orgpath.codes)
        patch = PathPatch(path)
        patches.append(patch)

    pc = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r'), edgecolors='black')
    pc.set_array(values)
    ax.add_collection(pc)
    hc.remove()

sized_hexbin(ax,hexbin)
plt.show()
```

[image: proposed solution]

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844600/hex-size-in-pyplot-hexbin-based-on-frequency ?

Comment: @plasmon360 I updated the post with my work from the proposed solution

Comment: When you use `C=df['Bin'],` it will not show the density, but rather the quantity that is in the `Bin` column. So the plot is correct. You can leave out `C` argument, and get the sizes based on the density.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest okay, gotcha. How can I color the hexes by the df['Bin']? I'd also like to be able to change the min size of the hexagons to be a little bit larger, is this possible?

Comment: The size is determined by the ratio `val/ma` in the code. You can replace it with whatever you find suitable. The colors is set via `pc.set_array(values)`; you can use something other than `values` of course.

Comment: I was able to get the size to change! Thanks for your help. But when I pass `df['Bin']` to `pc.set_array()` there are red hexes in the bottom left where there should only be blue hexes. How can I fix this?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest When I pass df['Bin'] to pc.set_array() there are red hexes in the bottom left where there should only be blue hexes. Is there a way to get an array in the shape of the values array that contains the values of the `df['Bin']` at each point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to spend sometime in understanding color mapping.

```
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(3)
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
    from matplotlib.path import Path
    from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['X'] = list(np.random.randint(100, size=100)) + list(np.random.randint(30, size=100))
    df['Y'] = list(np.random.randint(100, size=100)) + list(np.random.randint(30, size=100))

    df['Bin'] = df.apply(lambda row: .1 if row['X'] < 30 and row['Y'] < 30 else .9, axis=1)

    #fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    ax1 = plt.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'])

    fig,ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
    hexbin = ax2.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'], C=df['Bin'], gridsize=20,edgecolors='black',cmap= 'RdBu', reduce_C_function=np.bincount) #**

    def sized_hexbin(ax,hc):
        offsets = hc.get_offsets()
        orgpath = hc.get_paths()[0]
        verts = orgpath.vertices
        values = hc.get_array()
        ma = values.max()
        patches = []
        for offset,val in zip(offsets,values):
            v1 = verts*val/ma + offset
            path = Path(v1, orgpath.codes)
            patch = PathPatch(path)
            patches.append(patch)

        pc = PatchCollection(patches, cmap= 'RdBu', edgecolors='black')
        pc.set_array(values)

        ax.add_collection(pc)

        hc.remove()

    sized_hexbin(ax2,hexbin)
    cb = plt.colorbar(hexbin, ax=ax2)

    plt.show()

To plot the chart based on df['bins'] values - 

Need to change the reduce_C_function in #** marked line -

    hexbin = ax2.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'], C=df['Bin'], gridsize=20,edgecolors='black',cmap= 'RdBu', reduce_C_function=np.sum)

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv0U4.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb0gD.png

# Another variation of the chart :

# Where size is based on count of points in the bins and color is based on values of the df['bin']./ Also added if condition to control minimum hexbin size.


import numpy as np
np.random.seed(3)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from functools import partial

mycmp = 'coolwarm'

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['X'] = list(np.random.randint(100, size=100)) + list(np.random.randint(30, size=100))
df['Y'] = list(np.random.randint(100, size=100)) + list(np.random.randint(30, size=100))

df['Bin'] = df.apply(lambda row: .1 if row['X'] < 30 and row['Y'] < 30 else .9, axis=1)

#fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1 = plt.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'])


fig,ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
hexbin = ax2.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'], C=df['Bin'], gridsize=15,edgecolors='black',cmap= newcmp , reduce_C_function=np.bincount)
hexbin2 = ax2.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'], C=df['Bin'], gridsize=15,edgecolors='black',cmap= newcmp , reduce_C_function=np.mean)

def sized_hexbin(ax,hc,hc2):
    offsets = hc.get_offsets()
    orgpath = hc.get_paths()[0]
    verts = orgpath.vertices
    values1 = hc.get_array()
    values2 = hc2.get_array()
    ma = values1.max()
    patches = []

    for offset,val in zip(offsets,values1):
        # Adding condition for minimum size 
        if (val/ma) < 0.2:
            val_t = 0.2
        else:
            val_t = val/ma
        v1 =  verts*val_t + offset
        path = Path(v1, orgpath.codes)
        print(path)
        patch = PathPatch(path)
        patches.append(patch)

    pc = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=  newcmp)  #edgecolors='black'
    pc.set_array(values2)

    ax.add_collection(pc)
    hc.remove()
    hc2.remove()


sized_hexbin(ax2,hexbin,hexbin2)
cb = plt.colorbar(hexbin2, ax=ax2)

plt.xlim((-5, 100))
plt.ylim((-5, 100))

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I change the color based on the `df['Bin']` column?

Comment: So you don't want to see frequency in hexbin but the sum of df['Bin'] values ?

Comment: Yes, I want the color of the hexagons to be based on the `df['Bin']` column, so the bottom left hexes are blue and the others are red

Comment: I  added plot based on sum of the df['Bins']. You can edit cmap to manage color . Not sure if you are looking to do something else.

Comment: I don't want to color it based on the sum of the values in the bin, instead the value of the bin itself. Is there a way to do that? The colors would match the colors in the second plot of my example

Comment: What do you mean by value of the bin ? The bin is going to have a range - are you interested in publishing the range of the bin ?

Comment: The value of the bin is either .1 or .9, so I'd like the values with .1 (lower left) to be the same value of blue and the values with .9 (all the others) to be the same value of red.

Comment: Okay, you want the size to vary based on density of bins and color to vary based on value of bin. There would be only 2 color in the graph ?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. Is there a way to do that? When I pass df['Bin'] to pc.set_array() there are red hexes in the bottom left where there should only be blue hexes. Is there a way to get an array in the shape of the values array that contains the values of the df['Bin'] at each point?

Comment: Edited the code to include this. I am curious about need of such a specific chart.

Comment: This was correct! Thanks for your help. The final product is an NBA shot chart where the zones are colored based on the shooting percentage and the size of the dots is the frequency of shots taken

Comment: I've run in to a problem using np.bincount. Here's the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63571544/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-using-matplotlib-hexbins