# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence using matplotlib hexbins

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm getting a

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

when I use the hexbins function on matplotlib and I'm not sure why.

Here's the code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

np.random.seed(15)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y', 'val'])
df['X'] = np.random.randint(-226,227,300)
df['Y'] = np.random.randint(-27,462,300)
df['val'] = np.random.randint(0,3000,300)/1000
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
hexbin = ax.hexbin(df['X'], df['Y'], C=df['val'].values, reduce_C_function=np.bincount)
```

Comment: can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Why do you apply `np.bincount()`? The return value of `np.bincount(df['val'])` is `array([102, 98, 100])`, which may be the reason for this. If you don't specify it, the graph will be displayed.

Comment: @r-beginners I'm using np.bincount because I need to change the size of each hex based on the number of values that are in each bin and I'm using df['val'] as the bins

Comment: @Ethan, at the time in your code, `C` is the value accumulated in the bins, and the size of the bins is using the default value of 100 (you can change it with the `bins` keyword argument). The `reduce_C_function` cannot be used to change the bins size. If you want to adapt the size of the bins with respect to the output of `np.bincount`, you need to do it manually.

Comment: @Léonard how would I do something like that?

Comment: @Ethan, do you want do do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846615/5405298?

Comment: @Léonard I was looking to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072873/hex-size-in-matplotlib-hexbins-based-on-density-of-nearby-points I run in to the error for some of the iterations of the data on the first hexbin using np.bincount and I'm not sure why